# How to set success_url to redirect back to a model that is different from the one referenced in UpdateView?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

```
# models.py
class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField()

class Doctor(models.Model):
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Address)

class Patient(models.Model):
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
```

```
# views.py
class PatientDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Patient

class DoctorDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Doctor
class DoctorUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Doctor
    fields = ['locations']

class AddressUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Address
    fields = ['address']
```

I want to be able to go to AddressUpdateView from DoctorDetaillView or PatientDetailView, then be able to return back to DDV or PDV depending on whose view I was in.

I am able to route to AddressUpdateView from DDV/PDV by using the following:

```
# detailview1
{% for address in object.address.all %}
    <a href="{% url 'address-update' address.id %}">Update Address</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried

```
# detailview1
<a href="{% url 'address_update' adress.id %}?next={% url 'doctor_detail' object.id %}">Update Address</a>
```

but this url query parameter itself does not work. It just doesn't take me back to the doctor_detail url.

I know I need to add a success_url, reverse, or something in the manner but I just can't figure it out.
I can't explicitly put get_success_url to return back to Doctor because if it was an address update for a Patient, I don't want it going back to DoctorView, and vise versa.

Does anyone know how I can get back to the Doctor or Patient detailview from AddressUpdateView and correctly reverse it back to the respective view?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is to add a `get_context_data` function inside your view. Something like:

```py
class AddressUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Address
    fields = ['address']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  # [1]
        context['doctor'] = Doctor.objects.all()      # [2]
        return context
```

This just renders extra context into your template. Do remember that this function needs `[1]` to operate so don't remove it even if you aren't using it. For `[2]`, you can implement whichever filter you want to apply to get the appropriate doctor object.

So then you can do (assuming that the Doctor object also has an ID)

```html
<a href="{% url 'address_update' adress.id %}?next={% url 'doctor_detail' doctor.id %}"></a>
```

Comment: I just tried and added the get_context_data bit, but didn't work and still threw a "No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model." error, which also appears without using a get_absolute_url on the Address model. But if I set get_absolute_url, the AddressUpdateView just reroutes to AddressDetailView, which is not what I want.  I actually have that on my DoctorDetailView, too, where I'd put the a tag.

Comment: Sorry that I misunderstood your question. I thought you only need that in your template